# I can't seem to to find the time complexity of Histogram sort anywhere? I am aware it is type of bucket sort but what is the exact time complexity?

Tags: c++, sorting, bucket-sort

This is one implementation of a histogram. If you anybody has other examples and can explain the time complexity of histogram sort w.r.t that, it can also help.

Refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-make-histogram-array/ for more details:

```
// CPP program to make histogram of an array
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
      
    void printHistogram(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int maxEle = *max_element(arr, arr + n);
      
        for (int i = maxEle; i >= 0; i--) {
            cout.width(2);
            cout << right << i << " | ";
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      
                // if array of element is greater
                // then array it print x
                if (arr[j] >= i)
                    cout << " x ";
      
                // else print blank spaces
                else
                    cout << "   ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
      
        // print last line denoted by ----
        for (int i = 0; i < n + 3; i++)
            cout << "---";
      
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "     ";
      
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout.width(2); // width for a number
            cout << right << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
      
    // Driver code
    int main()
    {
        int arr[10] = { 10, 9, 12, 4, 5, 2,
                        8, 5, 3, 1 };
        int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        printHistogram(arr, n);
        return 0;
    }
```